# what is better: getSingleResult, or getResultList JPA

Tags: jpa

i need to retrieve single row from table, and i was interested what approach is better. 
On the one side `getSingleResult` is designed for retrieving single result, but it raises exception. Does this method have benefit in performance related to `getResultList` with

```
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(1);
```

Comment: "but it raises ecxeption." What exception is it raising? (Actually both of them can raise exception). I don't know about the performance (whichever is more performant, it should be negligible) but think `getSingleResult` makes your code more readable.

Comment: yes, i agree that getSingleResult much more readable. I just want to find out what aproach is more efficient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getSingleResult` throws `NonUniqueResultException`, if there are multiple rows. It is designed to retrieve single result when there is truly a single result.

The way you did is fine and JPA is designed to handle this properly. At the same time, you cannot compare it against `getSingleResult` any way, since it won't work.

However, depend on the code you are working on, it is always better to refine the query to return single result, if that's all what you want - then you can just call `getSingleResult`.

Comment: but i need to handle notFound exception. This part of code needs to get user account entity by email confirmation code there. I understand, that much clearer to use getSingleResult for this, but i'm aware of exception handling overhead

Comment: In combination with `fetch()` the usage of `setMaxResults(1)` can lead to a partially initialised objects. See below for an example.

Answer (score 24):

According to Effective Java by Joshua Bloch:

> Use checked exceptions for conditions from wich the caller can
>   reasonably be expected to recover. Use runtime exceptions to indicate
>   programming errors.

Credit to the source: [Why you should never use getSingleResult() in JPA](http://sysout.be/2011/03/09/why-you-should-never-use-getsingleresult-in-jpa/)

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Country.findByName", 
            query = "SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.name = :name"
public class Country {
  @PersistenceContext
  transient EntityManager entityManager;

  public static Country findByName(String name) {
      List<Country> results = entityManager
            .createNamedQuery("Country.findByName", Country.class)
            .setParameter("name", name).getResultList();
      return results.isEmpty() ? null : results.get(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, very reasonable explanation

Comment: There are very few absolutes in Java and the one this article preaches is not valid for all use cases. If for example the query should always return one row to satisfy some biz requirement why spend the cycles to marshall a list of results to check the count to see if the biz condition was violated when you can call getSingleResult and catch the NoResultException/NoUniqueResultException exceptions and take appropriate action? Its less code and it uses exceptions to enforce exceptional biz logic conditions.

Comment: @NBW short answer because exception handling is more resource consuming and generally considered an anti-pattern in thsi case http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107723/arguments-for-or-against-using-try-catch-as-logical-operators http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Comment: Any reason for no getSingleOrNullResult method ? Seems as it's a rather common need.

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative which I would recommend:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("your query");
List<Element> elementList = query.getResultList();
return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(elementList ) ? null : elementList.get(0);
```

This safeguards against Null Pointer Exception, guarantees only 1 result is returned.

Comment: why CollectionUtils instead of just elementList.isEmpty()?

Comment: @Tomasz Using the [http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty(java.util.Collection)], the isEmpty() returns true if list is null or empty. CollectionUtils provides easy code readability instead of having to write this: `(elementList != null) && !elementList.isEmpty().`

Comment: Which provider are you using? EclipseLink's [EJBQueryImpl.getResultList()](http://grepcode.com/file/maven.glassfish.org/content/repositories/eclipselink/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/2.1.1/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/EJBQueryImpl.java#EJBQueryImpl.getResultList%28%29) returns an empty list to begin with never null

Comment: @Tomasz You are correct in case of EclipseLink, `getResultList()` does not return null and null check is not needed. I was talking in general, with different provider implementations,it's better to have a null check IMO.

Comment: Hibernate as a provider never returns a null list either. I'm curious what provider would, exactly

Answer (score 1):

getSingleResult throws NonUniqueResultException, if there are multiple rows or no **any rows** . It is designed to retrieve single result when there is truly a single result.

Answer (score 1):

In combination with `fetch()` the usage of `setMaxResults(1)` can lead to a partially initialised objects. For example,

```
CriteriaQuery<Individual> query = cb.createQuery(Individual.class);
Root<Individual> root = query.from(Individual.class);
root.fetch(Individual_.contacts);

query.where(cb.equal(root.get(Individual_.id), id));

Individual i = em.createQuery(query)
    .setMaxResults(1) // assertion fails if individual has 2 contacts
    .getResultList()
    .get(0);
assertEquals(2, i.getContacts().size());
```

So, I am using `getResultList()` without limit -- a bit unsatisfying.