# Get single row in JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How to get single row from entity in JPA?

Table: Employee

```
    @Id
    private int empId;
    private String empName;
    ...
```

JPA by default return List. I`m trying to fetch single row.

EmployeeRepository :-

```
    public Employee findByEmpName(String empName);
```

**Another way is to do it, @Query should be use.**

```
    @Query(value="select e from Employee e where empName = ?1 limit 1", nativeQuery=true)
    public Employee findByEmpName(String empName);
```

How can i ensure that it return single row and correct result.
Any help appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JPQL doesnt have "LIMIT", as any basic JPA documentation would tell you, and `@Query` and XXXRepository is nothing to do with the JPA API either for that matter, it is Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to "ensure" anything.

If you dont have a collection of sort specified as return (e.g. `List<Employee>` instead of `Employee` ) and your query return more than one result it will launch a  `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements`.

If your query return more rows and you want only one of those either add a condition to differentiate which one of those rows you actually want or, if they are the same, add a good old `distinct`

> How can i ensure that it return single row and correct result.

That's your job when writing the query

Comment: Doesn't work with @Query and "nativeQuery = true"

Answer (score 20):

There is an out of the box solution, in repository you can name method as `findFirstBy...` or `findTopBy...`, that should do the thing.

You can find more in [Spring reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Answer (score 2):

JPA have a method to fetch a single row `getSingleResult`, but it's recommended to fetch a list and extract the first element over `getResultList`.

See:  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12094914/6673011)

Comment: Thanks, getSingleResult and getResultList can be used if we are making query and using entitymanager. But here i`m using JPARepository query method. link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods

Comment: @Akkave I haven't worked with Spring's JPARepository yet. Please edit your question that you use Spring's JPARepository.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only one row from the result set then you can limit number of records by using the **query.setMaxResults** method:while creating the jpa query.

example : criteria.setMaxResults(25); : it only fetch 25 records out of 100 records.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I`m not using JPA Criteria API, I`m using JPARepository.

Comment: Do you use query dsl to create queries?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation?noredirect=1&lq=1

maybe it can help

Answer (score -3):

In case someone wants just a single row from a database using JpaRepository (spring-data-jpa), I found this very useful:

```
repository.findAll().stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(...)
```

Since this is a stream, I suppose that rows (or rather: Objects) are fetched row by row.

Comment: I think this is a very heavy solution as you are fetching all records from the tale first. This is a stream but after you fetch it all from the database.