# Efficient way to get SingleResultObject in java

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a query to get the maximum id of a table Eg:Country.
Is there any efficient way to get a singleResultObject?
There is the possibility to get an Exception while getting a singleResultObject.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT MAX(c.countryId) FROM Country c ");

try   
{
   Integer countryId = (Integer) q.getSingleResult();    
}   
catch (Exception e)   
{
   logger.error("Exception " + e);       
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the query more efficient? or the code smaller?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002993/jpa-getsingleresult-or-null) might help.

Comment: Make code efficient and run without exception