# Filter Java Stream to 1 and only 1 element

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to use Java 8 [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)s to find elements in a `LinkedList`. I want to guarantee, however, that there is one and only one match to the filter criteria.

Take this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<User> users = new LinkedList<>();
    users.add(new User(1, "User1"));
    users.add(new User(2, "User2"));
    users.add(new User(3, "User3"));

    User match = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() == 1).findAny().get();
    System.out.println(match.toString());
}
```

---

```
static class User {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " - " + username;
    }

    int id;
    String username;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String username) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

This code finds a `User` based on their ID. But there are no guarantees how many `User`s matched the filter.

Changing the filter line to:

```
User match = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() < 0).findAny().get();
```

Will throw a `NoSuchElementException` (good!)

I would like it to throw an error if there are multiple matches, though. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `count()` is a terminal operation so you can't do that. The stream can't be used after.

Comment: Ok, thanks @ZouZou. I wasn't entirely certain what that method did. Why is there no `Stream::size` ?

Comment: @ryvantage Because a stream can only be used once: calculating its size means "iterating" over it and after that you can't use the stream any longer.

Comment: Wow. That one comment helped me understand `Stream`s so much more than I did before...

Comment: This is when you realize that you had needed to use a `LinkedHashSet` (assuming you want insertion order preserved) or a `HashSet` all along. If your collection is only used to find a single user id, then why are you collecting all the other items? If there is a potential that you will always need to find some user id which also needs to be unique, then why use a list and not a set? You are programming backwards. Use the right collection for the job and save yourself this headache

Comment: The solution can consume a large list and only at the end it will realize there are too many. In order to avoid this you could use .limit(2) before the collect statement.

Comment: @ryvantage Plus, Streams can potentially be infinite in length.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

#### Create a custom [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, T> toSingleton() {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            list -> {
                if (list.size() != 1) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
                return list.get(0);
            }
    );
}
```

We use [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to construct our desired `Collector` by

1. Collecting our objects in a `List` with the `Collectors.toList()` collector.
2. Applying an extra finisher at the end, that returns the single element — or throws an `IllegalStateException` if `list.size != 1`.

Used as:

```
User resultUser = users.stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getId() > 0)
        .collect(toSingleton());
```

You can then customize this `Collector` as much as you want, for example give the exception as argument in the constructor, tweak it to allow two values, and more.

#### An alternative — arguably less elegant — solution:

You can use a 'workaround' that involves `peek()` and an `AtomicInteger`, but really you shouldn't be using that.

What you could do instead is just collecting it in a `List`, like this:

```
LinkedList<User> users = new LinkedList<>();
users.add(new User(1, "User1"));
users.add(new User(2, "User2"));
users.add(new User(3, "User3"));
List<User> resultUserList = users.stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getId() == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (resultUserList.size() != 1) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
User resultUser = resultUserList.get(0);
```

Comment: Guava's `Iterables.getOnlyElement` would shorten these solutions and provide better error messages. Just as a tip for fellow readers who already use Google Guava.

Comment: i wrapped this idea up into a class - https://gist.github.com/denov/a7eac36a3cda041f8afeabcef09d16fc

Comment: The custom collector still collects all the items, which is `O(n)`, isn't there a way to shortcut it? Get a single item can be done in 1 step, checking if another one exists is also 1 step, no matter how many more items are in the filtered stream.

Comment: It's too bad Guava can't add some of these useful utilities... it's not the first time where a method has been in Guava for Iterable or Iterator, but there has been no built-in way to do the same thing for Stream. :(

Comment: Inspired by all these nice answers, what about this collector version (brevity) ? 
`Collectors.collectingAndThen(toList(), Iterables::getOnlyElement)`

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Please don't edit my code. It puts me in a situation where I need to validate my entire answer, which I have written four years ago, and I simply don't have the time for it right now.

Comment: I didn't change the spirit of your answer. Apart from one name, nothing changed. The first problem is that the answer is structured poorly by using "Update" blocks: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/316262

Comment: You have one code block which is completely unnecessary, since you improved on it with the next iteration. it should be removed. The last example you gave is the best one. It should be on top, as readers want to find good answers quickly. Please review the edits I made and you will see that they preserve the spirit of your answer and enhance the structuring. Also, SO was built on the idea of improving other posts by editing them. Please refrain from asking others to not edit your posts and don't roll back good edits

Comment: Please also read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367885/users-stating-that-they-do-not-want-their-posts-to-be-edited) and [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367886/4298200) on asking others not to edit your posts

Comment: @skiwi: Lonely's edit was helpful and correct, so I re-instated it after review. People visiting this answer today don't care about how you came to the answer, they don't need to see the old version and new version and an *Updated* section. That makes your answer more confusing and less helpful. It is much better to put posts in a *final state*, and if people want to see how it all played out they can view the post history.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But the code that is now in the answer is not the code that I have written, it has been changed. I'm personally fine with changes in the answer structure and text, but as I said I don't have time to review the changes to the code. And ultimately it's my name under the answer and I'd like to keep it that way. I'd prefer if the changes to the actual code (signature, names, etc.) would be reverted.

Comment: @skiwi: The code in the answer is *absolutely* what you have written. All the editor did was clean up your post, only *removing* an earlier version of the `singletonCollector()` definition obsoleted by the version that remains in the post, and renaming it to `toSingleton()`. My Java stream expertise is a bit rusty, but the renaming looks helpful to me. Reviewing this change took me 2 minutes, tops. If you don't have time to review edits, can I suggest that you ask someone else to do this in future, perhaps in the [Java chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/139/java)?

Comment: I have to say that I really don't like the name toSingleton, since that is misleading. It is not a singleton it returns, which I consider to be a reserved word in programming. This is a 'single element', or 'one instance'.

Comment: Great! In kotlin it's called single(). To provide more exception details throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("%d elements", list.size()));

Comment: This solution is not ideal, it collects all of the items and then fails if there are more than one. A better approach would be to have a fully custom collector that stops as soon as more than one items is processed.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Does that actually bother? I mean, you _expect_ to have one and only one element. If you will get multiple, I guess it won't be so many, that an O(n) operation is a problem.

Comment: @DánielSomogyi We're expecting one item *after* `filter`, before `filter` there could be millions/billions. If you look at the answer at the time of me writing that comment, you'll see it was doing collect *before* `filter` (`collectingAndThen`), so it does matter; or maybe just wasn't clear that it was supposed to be applied *after* a `filter`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob ohh, sure, mb, I was way too focused on the collecting itself. So actually, you want to filter, and after the second element passing through the filtering abort with an error. This avoids filtering the other god-knows-how-many elements. To answer your question: I guess the solution by reduction (e.g. by @assylias) would do that, or you use 3rd party packages like guava. You also could use a for-loop...

Comment: Using reduce is the most effective and compact way to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52006240/574147

Comment: .NET LINQ exposes a very simple to use `.Single` method - the fact that Java **still** does not have this natively built-in after **18** versions is so absurd to me.

Comment: As @FabioBonfante said, reduce will be more elegant and efficient.

Answer (score 176):

For the sake of completeness, here is the ‘one-liner’ corresponding to @prunge’s excellent answer:

```
User user1 = users.stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getId() == 1)
        .reduce((a, b) -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Multiple elements: " + a + ", " + b);
        })
        .get();
```

This obtains the sole matching element from the stream, throwing

- `NoSuchElementException` in case the stream is empty, or
- `IllegalStateException` in case the stream contains more than one matching element.

A variation of this approach avoids throwing an exception early and instead represents the result as an `Optional` containing either the sole element, or nothing (empty) if there are zero or multiple elements:

```
Optional<User> user1 = users.stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getId() == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> null));
```

Comment: I like the initial approach in this answer. For customization purposes, it is possible to convert the last `get()` to `orElseThrow()`

Comment: I like the brevity of this one, and the fact that it avoid creating an un-necessary List instance each time it is called.

Comment: In case your use case allows for the stream to be empty, omit the `.get()` on the end of the chain and then you'll get an `Optional` which will either be empty in case the stream is empty or will be populated with the single element.

Comment: I don't think its a good solution since in an error message we will have only first two elements which are invalid and we will not include value of more than two of them.

Comment: It is a great solution due to its brevity and comprehensibility.

Comment: Downvoting for a hacky solution on reducer as it provides misinformation - it will always show 2 values even if there is a lot more.

Comment: Caution: `Stream#reduce(...)` does behave differently than `Stream#collect(Collectors.reducing(...))`: Both make the stream return an `Optional`, however `Stream#reduce` will throw an NPE nevertheless when returning `null` inside the binary operator. So the code in the answer works, but it wont if you mix up the two code pieces

Comment: @Migol It may be worth re-reading the question. If the intent is to get the "sole" element, then anything other than that is not relevant.

Comment: The second solution is brilliantly concise and useful.

Answer (score 97):

The other answers that involve writing a custom [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) are probably more efficient (such as [Louis Wasserman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22695424/1441122), +1), but if you want brevity, I'd suggest the following:

```
List<User> result = users.stream()
    .filter(user -> user.getId() == 1)
    .limit(2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then verify the size of the result list.

```
if (result.size() != 1) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Expected exactly one user but got " + result);
}
User user = result.get(0);
```

Comment: What's the point of `limit(2)` in this solution? What difference would it make whether the resulting list was 2 or 100? If it's greater than 1.

Comment: It stops immediately if it finds a second match. This is what all the fancy collectors do, just using more code. :-)

Comment: How about adding `Collectors.collectingAndThen(toList(), l -> { if (l.size() == 1) return l.get(0); throw new RuntimeException(); })`

Comment: Javadoc says this about limit's param: `maxSize: the number of elements the stream should be limited to`. So, shouldn't it be `.limit(1)` instead of `.limit(2)` ?

Comment: @alexbt The problem statement is to ensure that there is exactly one (no more, no fewer) matching element. After my code, one can test `result.size()` to make sure it equals 1. If it's 2, then there's more than one match, so it's an error. If the code instead did `limit(1)`, more than one match would result in a single element, which can't be distinguished from there being exactly one match. This would miss an error case the OP was concerned about.

Comment: @StuartMarks Ah, got it, I don't know why I assumed `limit(...)` would throw when it goes beyond the limit. thanks

Answer (score 94):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides [`MoreCollectors.onlyElement()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#onlyElement--) which does the right thing here.  But if you have to do it yourself, you could roll your own `Collector` for this:

```
<E> Collector<E, ?, Optional<E>> getOnly() {
  return Collector.of(
    AtomicReference::new,
    (ref, e) -> {
      if (!ref.compareAndSet(null, e)) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Multiple values");
      }
    },
    (ref1, ref2) -> {
      if (ref1.get() == null) {
        return ref2;
      } else if (ref2.get() != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Multiple values");
      } else {
        return ref1;
      }
    },
    ref -> Optional.ofNullable(ref.get()),
    Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}
```

...or using your own `Holder` type instead of `AtomicReference`.  You can reuse that `Collector` as much as you like.

Comment: @skiwi's singletonCollector was smaller and easier to follow than this, that's why I gave him the check. But good to see consensus in the answer: a custom `Collector` was the way to go.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was primarily aiming for speed, not conciseness.

Comment: Yeah? Why is yours faster?

Comment: Mostly because allocating an all-up `List` is more expensive than a single mutable reference.

Comment: I was unable to get yours to compile

Comment: Compiles (and works great!) with change `AtomicReference::new` → `AtomicReference<E>::new`

Comment: Still having compile problems - Eclipse tells me "The method compareAndSet(capture#8-of ? extends Object, capture#8-of ? extends Object) in the type AtomicReference<capture#8-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (null, E)" for `!ref.compareAndSet(null, (E) e)`. If i don't cast to `E` in the 2nd argument, i get "The method compareAndSet(E, E) in the type AtomicReference<E> is not applicable for the arguments (null, Object)". For some reason the generics aren't being picked up properly. Wish it was working though, this is a great answer!

Comment: @LouisWasserman, the final update sentence about `MoreCollectors.onlyElement()` should actually be first (and perhaps the only :) )

Comment: Why not `return Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); })`?

Answer (score 83):

Use Guava's [`MoreCollectors.onlyElement()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#onlyElement()) ([source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/73e382fa877f80994817a136b0adcc4365ccd904/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.java#L83)).

> A collector that takes a stream containing exactly one element and returns that element. The returned collector throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if the stream consists of two or more elements, and a `NoSuchElementException` if the stream is empty.

This does what you want, throwing an exception if the stream does not contain exactly one element.

#### Usage:

```java
import static com.google.common.collect.MoreCollectors.onlyElement;

User match =
    users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() < 0).collect(onlyElement());
```

Comment: Note for other users: `MoreCollectors` is part of the yet unreleased (as of 2016-12) unreleased version 21.

Comment: This answer should go upper.

Answer (score 35):

The "escape hatch" operation that lets you do weird things that are not otherwise supported by streams is to ask for an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<T> it = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() < 0).iterator();
if (!it.hasNext()) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
} else {
    result = it.next();
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        throw new TooManyElementsException();
    }
}
```

Guava has a convenience method to take an `Iterator` and get the only element, throwing if there are zero or multiple elements, which could replace the bottom n-1 lines here.

Comment: Guava's method: Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterator<T> iterator).

Answer (score 27):

#### Update

Nice suggestion in comment from @Holger:

```
Optional<User> match = users.stream()
              .filter((user) -> user.getId() > 1)
              .reduce((u, v) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("More than one ID found") });
```

#### Original answer

The exception is thrown by `Optional#get`, but if you have more than one element that won't help. You could collect the users in a collection that only accepts one item, for example:

```
User match = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() > 1)
                  .collect(toCollection(() -> new ArrayBlockingQueue<User>(1)))
                  .poll();
```

which throws a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full`, but that feels too hacky.

Or you could use a reduction combined with an optional:

```
User match = Optional.ofNullable(users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() > 1)
                .reduce(null, (u, v) -> {
                    if (u != null && v != null)
                        throw new IllegalStateException("More than one ID found");
                    else return u == null ? v : u;
                })).get();
```

The reduction essentially returns:

- null if no user is found
- the user if only one is found
- throws an exception if more than one is found

The result is then wrapped in an optional.

But the simplest solution would probably be to just collect to a collection, check that its size is 1 and get the only element.

Comment: I would add an identity element (`null`) to prevent using `get()`. Sadly your `reduce` is not working as you think it does, consider a `Stream` that has `null` elements in it, maybe you think that you covered it, but I can be `[User#1, null, User#2, null, User#3]`, now it will not throw an exception I think, unless I'm mistaken here.

Comment: @Skiwi if there are null elements the filter will throw a NPE first.

Comment: Since you know that the stream can’t pass `null` to the reduction function, removing the identity value argument would render the entire dealing with `null` in the function obsolete: `reduce( (u,v) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("More than one ID found"); } )` does the job and even better, it already returns an `Optional`, eliding the necessity for calling `Optional.ofNullable` on the result.

Answer (score 22):

I think this way is more simple:

```
User resultUser = users.stream()
    .filter(user -> user.getId() > 0)
    .findFirst().get();
```

Comment: It find only first but the case was also to throw Exception when it is more than one

Comment: This is bad practice. It leads to nondeterministic behavior if there are 2 or more objects. Whole JDK's `findFirst` is bad idea.

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz 1) Isn't it only nondeterministic if it's a parallel stream? 2) If there are multiple items that fit the filter, how often do you care which one it is? (Calling it 'first' was probably the bad idea) 3) None of that applies to this post, because of what lczapski said.

Comment: It's nondeterministic because it selects first element while there might be many. Without explicit sorting, it's just randomly picking first one.

Answer (score 19):

#### Using reduce

This is the simpler and flexible way I found (based on @prunge answer)

```
Optional<User> user = users.stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getId() == 1)
        .reduce((a, b) -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Multiple elements: " + a + ", " + b);
        })
```

This way you obtain:

- the Optional - as always with your object or `Optional.empty()` if not present
- the Exception (with eventually YOUR custom type/message) if there's more than one element

Comment: This is clearly the most elegant of the solutions on this page.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs Thanks, given that there's also an answer from Brian Goetz on this page, it means really a lot ;-)

Answer (score 18):

An alternative is to use reduction:
(this example uses strings but could easily apply to any object type including `User`)

```
List<String> list = ImmutableList.of("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "two");
String match = list.stream().filter("two"::equals).reduce(thereCanBeOnlyOne()).get();
//throws NoSuchElementException if there are no matching elements - "zero"
//throws RuntimeException if duplicates are found - "two"
//otherwise returns the match - "one"
...

//Reduction operator that throws RuntimeException if there are duplicates
private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> thereCanBeOnlyOne()
{
    return (a, b) -> {throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate elements found: " + a + " and " + b);};
}
```

So for the case with `User` you would have:

```
User match = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() < 0).reduce(thereCanBeOnlyOne()).get();
```

Answer (score 11):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has a `Collector` for this called [`MoreCollectors.onlyElement()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#onlyElement--).

Answer (score 10):

#### Using a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html):

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Optional<T>> singleElementCollector() {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            list -> list.size() == 1 ? Optional.of(list.get(0)) : Optional.empty()
    );
}
```

---

#### Usage:

```
Optional<User> result = users.stream()
        .filter((user) -> user.getId() < 0)
        .collect(singleElementCollector());
```

---

We return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), since we usually can't assume the `Collection` to contain exactly one element. If you already know this is the case, call:

```
User user = result.orElseThrow();
```

This puts the burden of handeling the error on the caller - as it should.

Answer (score 5):

**Using Reduce and Optional**

From [Fabio Bonfante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52006240/6136489) response:

```
public <T> T getOneExample(Collection<T> collection) {
    return collection.stream()
        .filter(x -> /* do some filter */)
        .reduce((x,y)-> {throw new IllegalStateException("multiple");})
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("none"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) (very powerful [reactive extension](http://reactivex.io/) library)

```
LinkedList<User> users = new LinkedList<>();
users.add(new User(1, "User1"));
users.add(new User(2, "User2"));
users.add(new User(3, "User3"));

User userFound =  Observable.from(users)
                  .filter((user) -> user.getId() == 1)
                  .single().toBlocking().first();
```

The *single* [operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) throws an exception if no user or more then one user is found.

Comment: Correct answer, initialializing a blocking stream or collection is probably not very cheap (in terms of resources) though.

Answer (score 2):

As `Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper)` uses a throwing merger to handle multiple entries with the same key it is easy:

```
List<User> users = new LinkedList<>();
users.add(new User(1, "User1"));
users.add(new User(2, "User2"));
users.add(new User(3, "User3"));

int id = 1;
User match = Optional.ofNullable(users.stream()
  .filter(user -> user.getId() == id)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, Function.identity()))
  .get(id)).get();
```

You will get a `IllegalStateException` for duplicate keys. But at the end I am not sure if the code would not be even more readable using an `if`.

Comment: Fine solution! And if you do `.collect(Collectors.toMap(user -> "", Function.identity())).get("")`, you have a more generic behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a 3rd party library, [`SequenceM`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-sequence-api/7.1.0/com/aol/cyclops/sequence/SequenceM.html) from [cyclops-streams](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/tree/master/cyclops-streams) (and [`LazyFutureStream`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.simplereact/simple-react/0.99.6/com/aol/simple/react/stream/traits/LazyFutureStream.html) from [simple-react](https://github.com/aol/simple-react)) both a have single & singleOptional operators.

`singleOptional()` throws an exception if there are `0` or more than `1` elements in the `Stream`, otherwise it returns the single value.

```
String result = SequenceM.of("x")
                          .single();

SequenceM.of().single(); // NoSuchElementException

SequenceM.of(1, 2, 3).single(); // NoSuchElementException

String result = LazyFutureStream.fromStream(Stream.of("x"))
                          .single();
```

`singleOptional()` returns `Optional.empty()` if there are no values or more than one value in the `Stream`.

```
Optional<String> result = SequenceM.fromStream(Stream.of("x"))
                          .singleOptional(); 
//Optional["x"]

Optional<String> result = SequenceM.of().singleOptional(); 
// Optional.empty

Optional<String> result =  SequenceM.of(1, 2, 3).singleOptional(); 
// Optional.empty
```

---

Disclosure - I am the author of both libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I am using those two collectors:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Optional<T>> zeroOrOne() {
    return Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException("More than one value was returned");
    });
}

public static <T> Collector<T, ?, T> onlyOne() {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(zeroOrOne(), Optional::get);
}
```

Comment: Neat! `onlyOne()` throws `IllegalStateException` for >1 elements, and NoSuchElementException` (in `Optional::get`) for 0 elements.

Comment: @simon04 You could overload the methods to take a `Supplier` of `(Runtime)Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
Integer value  = list.stream().filter((x->x.intValue()==8)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

*I have used Integer type instead of primitive* as it will have null pointer exception.  you just have to handle this exception... looks succinct, I think ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tried a sample code for my self and here is the solution for that.

```
User user = Stream.of(new User(2), new User(2), new User(1), new User(2))
            .filter(u -> u.getAge() == 2).findFirst().get();
```

and the user class

```
class User {
    private int age;

public User(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Guava or Kotlin, here's a solution based on @skiwi and @Neuron answers.

```
users.stream().collect(single(user -> user.getId() == 1));
```

or

```
users.stream().collect(optional(user -> user.getId() == 1));
```

where `single` and `optional` are statically imported functions returning corresponding collectors.

I reasoned it would look more succinct if the filtering logic had been moved inside the collector. Also nothing would break in the code if you happened to delete the string with `.filter`.

The gist for the code https://gist.github.com/overpas/ccc39b75f17a1c65682c071045c1a079

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<state> getAllActiveState() {
    List<Master> master = masterRepository.getActiveExamMasters();
    Master activeMaster = new Master();
    try {
        activeMaster = master.stream().filter(status -> status.getStatus() == true).reduce((u, v) -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }).get();
        return stateRepository.getAllStateActiveId(activeMaster.getId());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        logger.info(":More than one status found TRUE in Master");
        return null;
    }
}
```

1. In this above code, As per the condition if its find more than one true in the list then it will through the exception.
2. When it through the error will showing custom message because it easy maintain the logs on server side.
3. From Nth number of element present in list just want only one element have true condition if in list there are more than one elements having true status at that moment it will through an exception.
4. after getting all the this we using get(); to taking that one element from list and stored it into another object.
5. If you want you added optional like `Optional<activeMaster > = master.stream().filter(status -> status.getStatus() == true).reduce((u, v) -> {throw new IllegalStateException();}).get();`

Answer (score -1):

```
User match = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId()== 1).findAny().orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalArgumentException());
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by @skiwi, I solved it the following way:

```
public static <T> T toSingleton(Stream<T> stream) {
    List<T> list = stream.limit(1).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return list.get(0);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
User user = toSingleton(users.stream().filter(...).map(...));
```

Comment: This solution does not detect the case where there are multiple values in the stream. So it goes unnoticed.

Comment: Actually, I only wanted to get the first element in the stream.

Comment: The original question wanted the one and only one. The accepted answer throws an exception instead.

Comment: Yeah... If you want to do exactly the same, you can just do `stream.findFirst().orElse(null)` which is completely equivalent and a lot more readable that what you are doing here.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this

```
long c = users.stream().filter((user) -> user.getId() == 1).count();
if(c > 1){
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

---

```
long count()
Returns the count of elements in this stream. This is a special case of a reduction and is equivalent to:

     return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();

This is a terminal operation.
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: It was said that `count()` is not good to use because it is a terminal operation.

Comment: If this really is a quote, please add your sources