# Java8 filter and return if only element

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

How can I filter a list using java8 streams and return the found element if it is the only element in the filtered list, otherwise(if there are more which meet the condition, or there is no result that meets the condition) return for example an `Optional.empty()`

I would need something like this:

Suppose I have a:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple","Banana","Peach");
```

then I want:

```
Optional<String> string = list.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.startsWith("A"))
    .findOne();
```

I know I can do it by:

```
boolean singleElement = list.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.startsWith("A"))
        .count() == 1;

String string = null;

if(singleElement){
  string = list.stream().filter(item -> item.startsWith("A")).iterator().next();
}
```

but I was wondering if I can do it in a single stream?

Is there any single stream solution?

Comment: You could `limit` the stream to `2`, collect it in a list, and then check whether it's exactly one element. This still has more than one line, but you are not doing any excess work.

Comment: Yeah that would help a little bit but for me still an extra work when I could get it somehow while it counts or limits the results.

Comment: If i can understand your question your input should be Apple if you only and only one result, otherwise you get empty?

Comment: @YCF_L exactly ]

Comment: I completely agree with @tobias_k.  Considering your requirement, does it really makes sense to do all these  for a simple thing at the expense of readability and simplicity. As you have rightly said, it will be like hunting a fly with cannon .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Java Stream to 1 and only 1 element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694884/filter-java-stream-to-1-and-only-1-element)

Comment: In my opinion, the best answer for the duplicated question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34663949/6770384).

Comment: @Socowi I had a look at that question but all of the answers which are reliable or give any king of solution, are done with throwing an exception. But I don't really care if there are more than one result, then I need simply and `Optional.empty()`

Comment: @Sunflame the second part of the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34663949/6770384) should return an `Optional` without exceptions.

Comment: @Socowi exactply I've just tried and works fine, one tiny question: I am using IntelliJ and it suggests to replace the `collect(Collectiors.reducing(...))` with simple reduce. but then I get NPE. Why do it suggests the replacement??

Comment: @Sunflame Only the IntelliJ developers could answer that reliably. I guess IntelliJ doesn't care for `Optional`s and thinks a normal variable would be as good as an `Optional` value.

Comment: @Socowi That was my idea, too, but I tried with `reduce`, which did not work. Added that to my answer, just for completeness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not very pretty, but you could `limit` the stream to 2 elements, `collect` those in a `List`, and see if that list has exactly one element. This still has more than one line, and has some overhead for creating the list, but that overhead is limited (to a list of size 2) and it does not have to iterate the stream twice, either.

```
List<String> tmp = list.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.startsWith("A"))
    .limit(2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Optional<String> res = tmp.size() == 1 ? Optional.of(tmp.get(0)) : Optional.empty();
```

(My other idea was to use `reduce((s1, s2) -> null)` after `limit(2)` and reduce any two matches to `null`, but instead of returning an `Optional.empty` this will just raise an Exception, i.e. it does *not* work, but maybe this triggers some better (working) ideas.)

---

Update: It seems like while `reduce` raises an Exceptions, `Collectors.reducing` does not, and instead returns an `Optional.empty` as desired, so this also works, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34663949/1639625) to a very similar question. Still, I'd add `limit(2)` to make it stop early:

```
Optional<String> res = list.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.startsWith("A"))
    .limit(2)
    .collect(Collectors.reducing((s1, s2) -> null));
```

(If you like this last part, please upvote the original answer.)

Comment: Thanks for both you and @Socowi, this works perfectly. A little bit annoying that IntellIJ doesn't like this, but I can disable the inspection for that ;) The upvote was done after Socowi showed me the answer :)

Comment: @tobias_k I like the limit more, as `reducing` is not really short circuiting. +1

Comment: Me too, without `.limit` the whole process took ~55ms with 1M strings and ~155ms with 10M strings, with `limit` both were ~40ms.

Comment: I would not rely on this behavior of the `reducing` collector. There is no indicator that this is intentional.

Answer (score 4):

You could use google `Guava` library's `MoreCollectors.onlyElement` as below:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Peach");
    String string = null;
    try {
        string = list.stream()
                .filter(item -> item.startsWith("A"))
                .collect(MoreCollectors.onlyElement());
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        System.out.println("zero or more than one elements found.");
    }
    Optional<String> res = string == null ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(string);
```

Notice it throws `NoSuchElementException` if there is no element and it throws `IllegalArgumentException` if there are more than one elements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this counts as a single operation to you, but you can do :

```
Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Peach")
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.partitioningBy(
                            x -> x.startsWith("A")),
                    map -> {
                        List<String> list = map.get(Boolean.TRUE);
                        return list.size() == 1 ? Optional.of(list.get(0)) : Optional.empty();
                    }));
```

Comment: It counts but I think this is something like when you are hunting for a fly with a cannon :D

Comment: What’s wrong with a `filter` before the `collect`? The logic of `collectingAndThen` would also work with the `toList()` collector and `partitioningBy`’s behavior of also collecting all the elements you are not interested in, is …not an advantage.

Comment: @Holger nothing is wrong with that, I've confused myself here :(