# Best way to handle when you are expecting 0 or 1 results from JPA query

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity which is expected to either be null or for there to be a single result.  Currently I'm handling this like so:

```
    Entity entity = null;
    try {
        entity = query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException ignore) {
        return null;
    }
    return entity;
```

But is this the "best" way of doing this?  I'm not a fan of ignoring exceptions but equally not a big fan of the only alternative I can think of:

```
    List<Entity> entities = null;
    entities = query.getResultList();
    if (entities.size() > 0) {
        return entities.get(0);
    }
    return null;
```

Comment: tried using `Optional` ?

Comment: http://sysout.be/2011/03/09/why-you-should-never-use-getsingleresult-in-jpa/

Comment: @daniu - That article is a bit narrow and assumptive.  I have a complex query which will result in one or null results. I don't use a NamedQuery for other reasons (code reuse of the predicates), so this is actually a genuine dilemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a discussion about this topic here:
[JPA getSingleResult() or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002993/jpa-getsingleresult-or-null)

Looks like there are no better alternatives.

Comment: Thanks - looks like this should be closed as a duplicate then... Curse my inability to find similar questions ;)