# JPA - getSingleResult vs LIMIT 1

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

What is the difference between `.getSingleResult()` and `LIMIT 1` for example in the below hibernate 6 query:

```
@Override
public Test customQuery3(Long id) {
return (Test) entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT NEW com.view.Test(a.id, b) FROM Author a " +
                        "LEFT JOIN Book b ON b.author.id=a.id " +
                        "WHERE b.id=:id " +
                        "GROUP BY a, b ORDER BY b.newestBook DESC LIMIT 1")
        .setParameter("id", id)
        .getSingleResult();
```

}

From reading SQL documentation `LIMIT 1` restricts the results to one and in the example above the newest.

The documentation on .getSingleResult() appears to do the same albeit with some errors thrown if the id is not found.

So why are both needed?

Comment: I think both are same albeit limit is in query level while getSingleResult() is api level. Also if someone messes up the query, the method ensures that is returns single result always.

Comment: `getSingleResult` was meant for queries that are *guaranteed* to return a single result, like `SELECT SUM / AVG` etc. For all queries that *might* return a single result (but might also return no results, depending on a business condition), `getResultList` was intended. Also remember that sometimes (e.g. with `FETCH JOIN`), **1 result = multiple result rows**, so `LIMIT 1` does not always make sense. For similar reasons, `setFirstResult() / setMaxResults()` is not always equivalent to setting `OFFSET / LIMIT / ROWNUM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F6%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult()) says if the query returned more than one row, it throws `NonUniqueResultException`. Besides, when using `getResultList()`, it returns a `List` rather than an `Object`. When you know it SHOULD return one row, better to use
`getSingleResult()`, because returning more rows in this case is a logic error or the data is in an inconsistent state, better to stop processing.

Comment: So are they doing the same thing, albeit some have better exception messages?

Comment: So LIMIT 1 just limits the results 1 (and has the sort) - whereas getOneResult doesnt get a single result from a resultlist, but is a check that the query returns 1.

Comment: @RayBond Yes, it basically act as a wrapper like: 1. Execute getResultList() and get the result. 2. Check if the result has and only has  one row.(turns out it throws Exception too when 0 rows is returned, since null has other meaning. Here's [another question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002993/jpa-getsingleresult-or-null)  ) 3. If everything goes as expected, return the row.