# JPA Query.getResultList() - use in a generic way

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm creating a complex query with multiple tables and need to list the result. Usually, I'm using the `EntityManager` and map the result to the JPA-Representation:

```
UserEntity user = em.find(UserEntity.class, "5");
```

Then I can access all values as the user `UserEntity` class defines it. But how can I access the field-values returned from a native, multiple-table query? What I get is a List of Objects. That's fine so far, but what "is" that Object? Array? Map? Collection? ...

```
//simpleExample
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT u.name,s.something FROM user u, someTable s WHERE s.user_id = u.id");
List list = query.getResultList();

//do sth. with the list, for example access "something" for every result row.
```

I guess the answer is quite simple, but most examples out there just show the usage when directly casting to a targetClass.

PS: In the example I could use the class-mappings of course. But in my case `someTable` is not managed by JPA, and therefore I don't have the entity nor do I have a class-representation of it, and since I'm joining like 20 tables, I don't want to create all the classes just to access the values.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

General rule is the following:

- If `select` contains single expression and it's an entity, then result is that entity
- If `select` contains single expression and it's a primitive, then result is that primitive
- If `select` contains multiple expressions, then result is `Object[]` containing the corresponding primitives/entities

So, in your case `list` is a `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: Hi, this results to a WARNING message in build... is there a way not to get that warning message `uses unchecked or unsafe operations`?

Comment: I mean aside from using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: Using Jackson and Java 8 streams:
`query.getResultList().stream().map(objectMapper::convertValue).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 61):

Since JPA 2.0 a `TypedQuery` can be used:

```
TypedQuery<SimpleEntity> q = 
        em.createQuery("select t from SimpleEntity t", SimpleEntity.class);

List<SimpleEntity> listOfSimpleEntities = q.getResultList();
for (SimpleEntity entity : listOfSimpleEntities) {
    // do something useful with entity;
}
```

Comment: `TypedQuery<SimpleEntity> q = em.createQuery("select t from SimpleEntity t");` ;)

Answer (score 13):

If you need a more convenient way to access the results, it's possible to transform the result of an arbitrarily complex SQL query to a Java class with minimal hassle:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select 42 as age, 'Bob' as name from dual", 
        MyTest.class);
MyTest myTest = (MyTest) query.getResultList().get(0);
assertEquals("Bob", myTest.name);
```

The class needs to be declared an @Entity, which means you must ensure it has an unique @Id.

```
@Entity
class MyTest {
    @Id String name;
    int age;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The above query returns the list of Object[]. So if you want to get the u.name and s.something from the list then you need to iterate and cast that values for the corresponding classes.

Comment: So, i assume that `list[x].object[0]` is the first value (u.name) and `list[x].object[1]` is the second (s.something) - so no `assoc` access?

Comment: If you printing just out object[i] and all primitives and date/time should be printed in their default format.

Comment: @ MGPJ Can you ellaborate answer with an example

Comment: Hi, this results to WARNING message `uses unchecked or unsafe operations`... is there a way to avoid the warning message?

Comment: I mean aside from using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and a simple solution that I found was:

```
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
for (Object[] result: results) {
    SomeClass something = (SomeClass)result[1];
    something.doSomething;
}
```

I know this is defenitly not the most elegant solution nor is it best practice but it works, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample on what worked for me.  I think that put method is needed in entity class to map sql columns to java class attributes.

```
    //simpleExample
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
"SELECT u.name,s.something FROM user u,  someTable s WHERE s.user_id = u.id", 
NameSomething.class);
    List list = (List<NameSomething.class>) query.getResultList();
```

Entity class:

```
    @Entity
    public class NameSomething {

        @Id
        private String name;

        private String something;

        // getters/setters



        /**
         * Generic put method to map JPA native Query to this object.
         *
         * @param column
         * @param value
         */
        public void put(Object column, Object value) {
            if (((String) column).equals("name")) {
                setName(String) value);
            } else if (((String) column).equals("something")) {
                setSomething((String) value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a bean with all required properties and cast the result using Java 8+ streams?

Like this:

```
public class Something {

    private String name;
    private String something;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And then:

```
import javax.persistence.Query;

...

Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT u.name,s.something FROM user u, someTable s WHERE s.user_id = u.id", Something.class);
List<?> list = query.getResultList();

return list
         .stream()
         .map(item -> item instanceof Something ? (Something) item : null)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That way, you don't need to return `List<Object[]>` nor hide the warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Ps.:

1 - I know that this post is very old. But... I'm here in 2021, so others will be coming here too =)

2 - This is wrong or bad practice? Let me know :D

Comment: This will cause `NullPointerException`, because `map` doesn't allow returning a `null`

Answer (score -1):

You can also update your hibernate to a version greater than 5.4.30.final