# JPA createNativeQuery getResultList List<Object[]> skipping fields that are null

Tags: java, sql, jpa

We are using JPA's createNativeQuery such that we get back a `List<Object[]>`; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13701011/34806

Our Java code expects to be able to iterate through the list and get back Object arrays with a *fixed* number of "fields" (`Object`s in the `Object` array).  However if any of those fields were null in the database, the Object[] array does not contain them, instead skipping such null fields entirely such that the "row" (`Object[]` array in the `List`) contains fewer fields than other rows -- this is obviously problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to use coalesce in the query's SQL for each nullable field, to return a default value other than null.  For instance the following:

```
SELECT EMPNO, COALESCE(SALARY, 0) FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Will return 0 if Salary was null.  See: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000780.html  NOTE: I just replaced the previous link because it no longer worked, sadly that may happen again :(  I guess just google for "database coalesce" in that case.