# Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<String>

Tags: java

I have this method where I cast the results to (List ) , but my eclipse is still complaining !  **Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List**

```
@Override
public List<String> getDevices(Long productId) {

        String queryString = "SELECT op.name FROM t_operation op WHERE op.discriminator = 'ANDROID' and PRODUCT =:productId ";

        try {
            Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
            query.setParameter("productId", productId);

            return (List<String> ) query.getResultList();


        } catch (RuntimeException re) {         
            throw re;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @ar4ers `java.util.List` as stated in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList())

Comment: Use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get this warning due runtime check cast.

Even if you use `if(query.getResultList() instanceof List<?>)` you will get this warning, so...

- use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` or
- use generics

Comment: what do you mean by *use generics* Isnt `List<String>` not generics?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java your way is called wildcards  if I am not wrong

Comment: agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card

Answer (score 8):

Please don't use `@SuppressWarnings` and don't type cast, because these are error-prone ways to do this. Follow the advice given in the following answer to a similar question and use `TypedQuery` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21354639/3657198

```
TypedQuery<SimpleEntity> q = 
    em.createQuery("select t from SimpleEntity t", SimpleEntity.class);

List<SimpleEntity> listOfSimpleEntities = q.getResultList();
for (SimpleEntity entity : listOfSimpleEntities) {
    // do something useful with entity;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can sure use TypedQuery with the parameter types is String in this case. So what you need is

```
TypedQuery<String> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString, String.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

You may want to use this special hack to return the correct type. It works with any type of object since `String#valueOf(Object)` exists

```
try {
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter("productId", productId);
    return query.getResultList().stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (RuntimeException re) {         
    throw re;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a `TypedQuery`?

Comment: @JonK This may be a solution also. Feel free to edit my post if you know how to do. I know it's something like `TypedQuery<String> query = ...createNamedQuery...` but am not sure