# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: java, list, arraylist

There are two data in text file. I trying to retrieve them out but I get below errors

```
##########  Error with java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;  ##########
Size 1
```

**Code**

```
 try {
        File file = new File(filePath + "ABC.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String st;
        List list = new ArrayList();

        try {
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String id = st.substring(92, 100);
                try {
                    list.add(getDetail(id));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (Object[] o : (List<Object[]>) list) {
                    Details x = new Details();
                    x.setType(o[0].toString());
                     ....
                }
            }

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.printError(Reader.class, "Error with " + ex);
        }
        logger.printInfo(Reader.class, "Size " + list.size());
      
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Query**

```
public List getDetail(int id){
        StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder();
         bf.append("SELECT ");
         bf.append("'ABC', ");
                ....
        return em.createQuery(bf.toString()) .getResultList();
    }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Well yes, you're trying to cast a `List` to an `Object[]`. That won't work - it's not clear why you expected it to work. To put it another way - ignoring all the *outer* list part, you're trying to write something like `Object[] o = (Object[]) getDetail(id);`. Would you expect *that* to work? (It's also very unclear why you're iterating over the list on every iteration of your while loop...)

Comment: @JonSkeet How can I solve this ?

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to do, so we can't tell you how to solve it - we can only tell you why you're getting the problem you're getting. (You haven't shown us how you're trying to use `o` within your loop.)

Comment: @JonSkeet edited.

Comment: The error message should be different. The cast is from `List<Object>` to `List<Object[]>` in the for loop.  Tony, nobody can help debug or advise on a program that's so shoddily posted.

Comment: Okay, so we now know that you're calling `o[0].ToString()` - but what's that meant to represent? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and clarify your question a lot.

Comment: Can you please post your _complete_ getDetail() method? Using JPA, you should perhaps use a `TypedQuery` and avoid using `Object[]` (that's so 1980s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be related to [Query](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList--) API.

SO here, i would suggest to use like

```
public List<Object[]> getDetail(int id){
        StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder();
         bf.append("SELECT ");
         bf.append("'ABC', ");
                ....
        return em.createQuery(bf.toString()) .getResultList(); -- getResultList returns List.
    }
```

And then

```
List<Object[]> list=new Arraylist<Object[]>();
 .....
 list.addAll(getDetail(id));  -- as we are adding collection here.
```

instead of

```
list.add(getDetail(id));
```

in original code.

For more info, you can refer existing [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700565/jpa-query-getresultlist-use-in-a-generic-way)

Comment: no suitable method found for add(List<Object[]>)
    method Collection.add(Object[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; List<Object[]> cannot be converted to Object[])
    method List.add(Object[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; List<Object[]> cannot be converted to Object[])
----

Comment: @Tony modified code, please check.

Comment: I will get list with sizes 3. The first and second are duplicated

Comment: @Tony Ok, in that case, you need to still use `list.add(getDetail(id).get(0));` to get only single , first list. though this is not full proof solution. But this will avoid your duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use [generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html):

```
        List<Details> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String id = st.substring(92, 100);
                try {
                    list.addAll(getDetail(id)); // add all results
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.printError(Reader.class, "Error with " + ex);
        }
```

Your `getDetail` method should return rows converted to list of Details

```
public List<Details> getDetail(int id){ 
    // prepare your query
    StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder();
    bf.append("SELECT ");
    bf.append("'ABC', ");

    // iterate over search results and convert each row into Details
    List<Details> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(bf.toString());
    while (rs.next()) {
       results.add(toDetails(rs)); // convrt single row to Details model
    }
    return results;
}
```

Convert single [result row](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) to `Details`:

```
private Details toDetails(ResultSet rs){
    Details x = new Details();
    x.setType(rs.getString(0));
    ...
    return x;
}
```

Comment: incompatible types: List cannot be converted to Object[] in getDetail method

Comment: @Tony: Hence "do a conversion here if needed".

Comment: @JonSkeet How to convert ?

Comment: @Tony: Well, you could use `toArray()` potentially - but it feels like you're concentrating on getting a quick fix rather than taking a step back and considering *why* there's a problem and what the *best* solution is.

Comment: @JonSkeet Strange...`##########  Error with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1  ##########
 Size 1`

Comment: Obj cannot converted to Obj[]

Comment: @Tony: Well you can't have *both* of those problems, as one is an exception and one is a compile-time error. You *still* haven't explained what you're trying to do - this is a real XY problem at the moment, and you should take a step back to make sure *you* know in detail what you're trying to do, then explain that in the question.