# How to parse an Object that has no keys

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following query:

```
public List<Object> findNearbyGangs(double lat, double lng, double distance) {
    Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT id, (6371 * acos (cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(:longitude))  + sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM Gang g GROUP BY id HAVING distance < :distance ORDER BY distance")
        .setParameter("latitude", lat)
        .setParameter("longitude", lng)
        .setParameter("distance", distance);

    List<Object> objects = query.getResultList();
    return objects;
}
```

`objects` contains

```
[
    [
        3,
        0
    ],
    [
        321,
        0
    ],
    [
        353,
        1.3575295456440253
    ]
]
```

How do I parse this object so that id = 3 and distance = 0, id = 321 and distance = 0, and so on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Query.getResultList() - use in a generic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700565/jpa-query-getresultlist-use-in-a-generic-way)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
public List<NearbyGang> getNearbyGangs(Double longitude, Double latitude, int radius) {
        List<Object> nearbyGangsFromDatabase = this.gangRepositoryImpl.findNearbyGangs(longitude, latitude, radius);
        List<NearbyGang> nearbyGangs = new ArrayList<NearbyGang>();
        for (Object object : nearbyGangsFromDatabase) {
            Class oClass = object.getClass();
            if (oClass.isArray()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(object); i++) {
                    BigInteger gangId = (BigInteger) Array.get(object, 0);
                    Gang gang = this.getById(gangId.longValue()).get();

                    Double distance = (Double) Array.get(object, 1);

                    NearbyGang nearbyGang = new NearbyGang(gang, distance);
                    nearbyGangs.add(nearbyGang);
                }
            }
        }
        return nearbyGangs;
    }
```