# How to convert Array of Object to Custom Class Object (that is array to object)?

Tags: java, jpa

I am working on a spring boot project and using JPA for querying the database with Entity manager.

i.e.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = 1"); // SUPPOSE

List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
```

now after this what I want to achieve here is creating an Object of that corresponding result.

```
i.e.  ResultObject obj = (ResultObject) result.get(0); 
// here ResultObject is user defined.
```

but this type of casting is not possible directly.

so what I am currently doing is:

```
ResultObject obj = new ResultObject(); 
obj.setArribute1((String) obj[0]);
obj.setArribute2((Integer) obj[1]);
...
```

**and on average i will be having 15 attributes per object. so its really tiresome...**

I have tried using:

```
List<ResultObject> obj = (List<ResultObject>)query.getResultList();
```

**but doesn't work.**

Comment: I think a similar question is mentioned here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700565/jpa-query-getresultlist-use-in-a-generic-way

Comment: So use JPA as it's intended and use a JPQL query of `SELECT new ResultClass...`

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- You can't use constructor expression with native queries

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I meant to say "JPQL query" (updated), but that was the exact point of "JPQL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use ConstructorResult (JPA) or ResultTransformer (Hibernate) or QLRM.

ConstructorResult is JPA standard and you have to create a Annotation with the column mapping:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "BookValueMapping",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = BookValue.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "title"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "version", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "authorName")}))
```

From https://thorben-janssen.com/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/

And ResultTransformer is Hibernate proprietary and you must use the Hibernate session:

```
List<PersonSummaryDTO> dtos = session.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT p.id as \"id\", p.name as \"name\" " +
    "FROM Person p")
.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( PersonSummaryDTO.class ) )
.list();
```

From https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-dto-query

Or QLRM is a library that maps the result to a DTO using the constructor:

```
JpaResultMapper jpaResultMapper = new JpaResultMapper();

Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ID, NAME FROM EMPLOYEE");
List<EmployeeTO> list = jpaResultMapper.list(q, EmployeeTO.class);
```

https://github.com/72services/qlrm

Comment: qlrm works for me, but just a small issue. it does not perform wide conversion (type casting for Byte to Integer) ... It works by creating special constructor for this. thanks though...

Comment: QLRM is very basic. I decided not to implement conversion because of the other options

Comment: how can I do the one to many mapping using QLRM, is it possible? and is there some sort of documentation for this?

Comment: No that's not possible. Because the goal of QLRM is to map a result of a query to a DTO. And the result of a query is always a flat ResultSet

Comment: so what do you suggest in this case what's the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest creating a POJO that can be mapped to your table you're retrieving values from:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m")})
public class MyTable implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "display_name")
  private String displayName;
  

  public MyTable() {
  }

  public MyTable(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public MyTable(Integer id, String name, String displayName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.displayName = displayName;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
  }

  public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof MyTable)) {
      return false;
    }
    MyTable other = (MyTable ) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "MyTable[ id=" + id + " ]";
  }
  
}
```

Obviously fill in the fields as you need with the corresponding database datatype repersentation.

Notice how i have `NamedQueries`  we can now take advantage of those named queries to do our fetches

```
TypedQuery<MyTable> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("MyTable.findAll", MyTable.class);
List<MyTable> results = query.getResultList();
```

this will do all the casting and conversions for you. You can add all the named queries you want.

https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named

**UPDATE**

If you need to dynamically create a query you can do the following:

```
String query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m Where m.id =:id and m.name=:name"; 
///modify the query as needed based off of other conditions)

TypedQuery<MyTable > query = em.createQuery(query, MyTable .class);
query.setParameter("id", id);
query.setParameter("name", name);

List<MyTable> results = query.getResultList();
```

https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/api

Comment: Can named query be dynamic? I need to you different joins based on stored procedures as well is it possible to do so?

Comment: Named queries cannot be dynamic but you can craft your JPQL query and execute that. See my edit. Also can check out the link https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/api to help you further

Answer (score 0):

if you have set up a DatabaseConfig like this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa) then you can simply create a class that you annotate with `@Entity` and `@Table(name = "yourDatabaseTableName")` Don't forget to define:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

and annotate all your colums with `@Column(name = "databaseColumnName")`
Then, create an interface that you annotate with `@Repository` which `extends JpaRepository<YourEntityClass, Long>`where the Long-parameter is the type you've given to the id-variable of your Entity.

Now you can use simple JPA-methodqueries like `findAll()` or you can create your own JPQL-queries like:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e "
        + "WHERE e.id = :id")
Optional<Entity> findById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

It's even possible to use NativeQueries in this way:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Entity e "
        + "WHERE e.id = :id",
        nativeQuery = true)
Optional<Entity> findById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert **Object[] array** results into Map of instances which will be key value pairs as columns and their subsequent values, by using the custom algorithm I built. And later on you can use the map instance to construct your custom bean via constructor or setters.

```
/**
 * method to convert and transform an array of objects into a list of map instances, consisting columns as keys
 * and their subsequent values
 *
 * @param arrays - a list of object type array instances, representing the values retrieved from a SQL query
 * @param query  - a string value representing the SQL query which has retrieved the Object array values
 *
 *               <p> Note : The String Query must satisfy the below statements</p>
 *               <p> 1. Query must not contain any of \n or \t in it.</p>
 *               <p> 2. Query must not contain asterick, instead should contain all the concrete column names.</p>
 *               <p> 3. All the FROM keyword inside the query should be either fully capitalised or fully non capitalised i.e. FROM or from. </p>
 * @return
 * @author - Harsh Sharma
 */
public List<Map<String, Object>> convertQueryResultIntoMap(List<Object[]> arrays, String query) {
    // base cases
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(arrays) || query == null || query.equals("")) return null;
    int lastFROMClauseIndex = -1;
    char[] arr = query.toCharArray();
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (i - 3 > -1 && ((arr[i] == 'M' && arr[i - 1] == 'O' && arr[i - 2] == 'R' && arr[i - 3] == 'F')
                || (arr[i] == 'm' && arr[i - 1] == 'o' && arr[i - 2] == 'r' && arr[i - 3] == 'f'))) {
            lastFROMClauseIndex = i - 3;
            if (stack.isEmpty()) break;
        } else {
            if (arr[i] == ')') stack.push(arr[i]);
            else if (arr[i] == '(') stack.pop();
        }
    }

    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder columnName = new StringBuilder("");
        if (i < arr.length - 1 && arr[i] == ',') {
            int anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex = -1;
            int lastAlphabetEncounteredIndex = -1;
            int j = i - 1;
            for (; j > -1; j--) {
                if (anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex != -1 && (arr[j] == ' ' || arr[j] == '.')) break;
                if (arr[j] != ' ') {
                    if (lastAlphabetEncounteredIndex == -1) lastAlphabetEncounteredIndex = j;
                    anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex = j;
                }
            }
            for (; anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex <= lastAlphabetEncounteredIndex; anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex++) {
                columnName.append(arr[anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex]);
            }
            if (!columnName.toString().equals("")) {
                columnNames.add(columnName.toString());
            }
        } else if (i == lastFROMClauseIndex) {
            int anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex = -1;
            int lastAlphabetEncounteredIndex = -1;
            int j = i - 1;
            for (; j > -1; j--) {
                if (anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex != -1 && (arr[j] == ' ' || arr[j] == '.')) break;
                if (arr[j] != ' ' && arr[j] != '.') {
                    if (lastAlphabetEncounteredIndex == -1) lastAlphabetEncounteredIndex = j;
                    anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex = j;
                }
            }
            for (; anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex <= lastAlphabetEncounteredIndex; anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex++) {
                columnName.append(arr[anyAlphabetEncounteredIndex]);
            }
            if (!columnName.toString().equals("")) {
                columnNames.add(columnName.toString());
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(arrays) && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(columnNames)) {
        int columnSize = columnNames.size();
        for (Object[] dbData : arrays) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnSize; i++) {
                map.put(columnNames.get(i), dbData[i]);
            }
            mapList.add(map);
        }
    }
    return mapList;
}
```