# Converting Query to TypeQuery gives java.lang.AbstractMethodError Exception

Tags: java, jpa, casting, persistence

I was trying to `SELECT` from `createQuery` like this:

```
Query query3 = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Tag t WHERE t.name IN (:tag1, :tag2)");
query3.setParameter("tag1", "tag1");
query3.setParameter("tag2", "tag2");
Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>(query3.getResultList());
```

This code works fine, however I got this warning:

> Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List

So, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957394/java-persistence-cast-to-something-the-result-of-query-getresultlist#12157248), I replce `Query` with `TypedQuery` like this:

```
TypedQuery<Tag> query2 = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Tag t WHERE t.name IN (:tag1, :tag2)", Tag.class);
query2.setParameter("tag1", "tag1");
query2.setParameter("tag2", "tag2");
Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>(query2.getResultList());
```

The warning is disappeared, but when I run it, it produces a run-time error like this:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
at ut.ConfTest.testCreatePost(ConfTest.java:269)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Did I mess up something with TypedQuery?

Comment: so something (OpenEJB) is using a different version of JPA than what you expect. Look at the respective versions of OpenEJB, your JPA provider, the JPA API jar, etc

Comment: @NeilStockton I'm using **openejb-3.1.4** and **EclipseLink 2.6**, which seems to use **javax.persistence_2.1.1** according to the jar file name. I thought TypedQuery is usable in JPA 2.x.

Comment: eclipselink uses JPA 2.1, yes. Does OpenEJB? because it is OpenEJB that the exception complains about not implementing a JPA 2 method, and my strong suggestion based on that error message is NO it does not, it is built against JPA 1!

Comment: @NeilStockton Ok I see, according to [Apache OpenEJB 3.1.4](http://tomee.apache.org/download/apache-openejb-3.1.4.html), it seems **OpenEJB 3.1.4** only supports **OpenJPA 1.2.1**. Looks like I uses a old version of OpenEJB which is not support JPA 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception commonly occurs when we use an old version of an `interface` implementation which is missing a new `interface` method. You can check the older version method you are using in your code and change this method with latest version.

it might be cause of due to some `version` compatibility.